# Methods to extract email signature

Tags: python, pandas, email, parsing, dataframe

I would like to extract email signatures from a single-column Pandas data frame where each row contains a discrete email message as a string. Some emails are HTML encoded and some are not. They can be of any email provider (e.g.: Gmail, Microsoft, Yahoo, etc.).

I know that Gmail signatures are contained in a div where `class="email_signature"` which simplifies parsing those. My dilemma is: what is the best way to extract non-gmail email signatures? Is there a regex that captures the content of an email? How can I apply this regex over the Pandas data frame in Python?

I'd provide an example but the data is private and frankly I don't think it's necessary for this question.

Comment: We need a minimal working example in order tobe helpful.  What have you tried?

Comment: You should research those three questions you ask in your post, write code based on what you find, and then come back here and repost a specific question based on what your results were.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout SigParser.com. It is an API for doing this pretty much. It uses email signatures to extract contact data. Is this what you're looking for?